# iframe in jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, html

i have written information to jquery accordions like this:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Gauk geriausią pasiūlymą dujų įrangos montavimui!</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
<iframe src="http://www.citavicius.lt/egas/forma/index.php" width="500" height="240" frameborder="0">
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Paskaičiuok tiksliau</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
```

But then I run file, it shows me only first item from accordion with iframe, but not showing second item from accordion.

How to solve this problem, to view all items?

Comment: Please show the jQuery code. We can't tell anything from this.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to close your iframe?
    
I know it's a dummy answer, but that may be the reason :)

Comment: That dummy answer helped me! It's funny to forget such simple things after lot of work :) Thanks!